# JavaScript: Move elements up and down in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a script to move list elements up and down with a button click.

I can make it work with jQuery, but I have troubles writing this in pure (vanilla) JavaScript.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.up').on('click', function(e) {
    var wrapper = $(this).closest('li')
    wrapper.insertBefore(wrapper.prev())
  })
  $('.down').on('click', function(e) {
    var wrapper = $(this).closest('li')
    wrapper.insertAfter(wrapper.next())
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
  <li>2 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
  <li>3 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
  <li>4 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
  <li>5 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
  <li>6 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I do the same in plain JavaScript?

Comment: With "plain javascript" do you mean without jQuery?

Comment: Yes, without jQuery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```js
window.onload = function () {
 var upLink = document.querySelectorAll(".up");

 for (var i = 0; i < upLink.length; i++) {
  upLink[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
   var wrapper = this.parentElement;

   if (wrapper.previousElementSibling)
       wrapper.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, wrapper.previousElementSibling);
  });
 }

 var downLink = document.querySelectorAll(".down");

 for (var i = 0; i < downLink.length; i++) {
  downLink[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
   var wrapper = this.parentElement;

   if (wrapper.nextElementSibling)
       wrapper.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper.nextElementSibling, wrapper);
  });
 }
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>1 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
 <li>2 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
 <li>3 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
 <li>4 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
 <li>5 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
 <li>6 <a class='up' href='#'>up</a> <a class='down' href='#'>down</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below code

`function listbox_move(listID, direction) {

```
var listbox = document.getElementById(listID);
var selIndex = listbox.selectedIndex;

if(-1 == selIndex) {
    alert("Please select an option to move.");
    return;
}

var increment = -1;
if(direction == 'up')
    increment = -1;
else
    increment = 1;

if((selIndex + increment) < 0 ||
    (selIndex + increment) > (listbox.options.length-1)) {
    return;
}

var selValue = listbox.options[selIndex].value;
var selText = listbox.options[selIndex].text;
listbox.options[selIndex].value = listbox.options[selIndex + increment].value
listbox.options[selIndex].text = listbox.options[selIndex + increment].text

listbox.options[selIndex + increment].value = selValue;
listbox.options[selIndex + increment].text = selText;

listbox.selectedIndex = selIndex + increment;
```

}`

Refrerence [Example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/listbox-select-all-move-left-right-up-down-javascript/)

Comment: The question is regarding moving `li` elements up/down.